# disable postgresql constraints by jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, constraints

I am trying to insert data into db using JDBC,
when doing so I have to disable constraints - check, not-null, foreign-keys.

```
alter table user_table disable trigger all;
```

I have tried with the above query it doesn't work.

I need a way to disable all the constraints at start of the program, and when transaction are completed I need to enable the constraints back.

I am using JDBC4 and Postgresql 9.0.

Comment: How are you executing the alter table statement (code)?

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is neither a valid PostgreSQL error message nor a valid Java Exception

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html) says for the `ALL` part:

> Disable or enable all triggers belonging to the table. ( This requires **superuser privilege** if any of the triggers are internally generated constraint triggers such as those that are used to implement foreign key constraints or deferrable uniqueness and exclusion constraints.)

So I **guess** that the user you are using to insert the data is not a superuser since you list foreign key checks in your question.

However: Unless your requirements are **very** special I think you are on the wrong route:

Disabling the checks / triggers all together is a very big gun which wrecks your data consistency quite easily. And since you want to re-enable the checks at the end of the transaction it seems you don't want to do this.

It would be better if you can get away with deferrable constraints at the beginning. Then you can use the [SET CONSTRAINTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set-constraints.html) command which is automatically bound to the transaction scope. You can be *sure* that your consistency is not at risk. Lookup also the [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) documentation regarding deferrable triggers.